# Use formal proof to determine if two translations are equivalent or not

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

My logic professor just assigned our class this question that's got us all stumped. We'd appreciate your help.

> We have found 2 translations for 'all logicians other than Aristotle are evil' namely  $\forall x((Lx\land \lnot a=x)\to Ex)$ and $\lnot\exists x(Lx\land\lnot E x\land\lnot x=a)$. Use formal proof to determine whether these two translations are equivalent or not. That is, show the inference from one to the other is valid/invalid and vice versa. Give counterexample if invalid.

How would we go about doing this proof? Thanks, we appreciate your help!

Comment: What proof system are you using?  (Rules of inference, axioms, display format, etc.)

Comment: Are you given a set of equivalence principles, like De Morgan?

Comment: 1st step) use the equivalence of $\forall$ with $\lnot \exists \lnot$.

Comment: 2nd step) use the propositional equivalence of $\lnot (p \to q)$ with $(p \land \lnot q)$.

Comment: We are using a rules of inference system (NIF, DE, DU, NOR, OR, etc). We weren't given a set of equivalence principles, I posted the problem in its entirety. And @ Mauro your method makes sense to me but I don't think it's the rules of inference system our professor expects.

Comment: Introduction to Logic 3rd edition by Harry Gensler

Comment: NOR, NIF etc are rules we are given and we use them in our proofs. For example NIF would say ~(P-->Q) we can derive P as well as ~Q.

Comment: My 1st step (see comment above) uses RS (page 246) to get from $\lnot \exists x (\ldots)$ to $\forall x \lnot (\ldots)$.

Comment: @jzaza: You need to show what the rules in your inference system are (not just recite the _names_ your book is using for them).

Answer (score 1):

the two translations are equivalent:
    $$1)~  (∀x)((Lx∧¬a=x)→Ex)~~~~~$$
    $$2)~ ¬¬(∀x)((Lx∧¬a=x)→Ex)$$
    $$3)~ ¬(∃x)¬((Lx∧¬a=x)→Ex)$$
    $$4)~ ¬(∃x)¬(¬(Lx∧¬a=x)∨Ex)$$
    $$5)~ ¬(∃x)((Lx∧¬a=x)∧¬Ex)~~$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* [ref.to : Harry Gensler, [Introduction to Logic (3rd ed., 2017)](https://books.google.it/books?id=gC4lDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)].

For the direction : $\lnot \exists x (\ldots) \to \forall x (\ldots)$.

1) $¬∃x(Lx∧¬Ex∧¬x=a)$ --- premise

2) $∀x ¬(Lx∧¬Ex∧¬x=a)$ --- from 1) by (RS) [page 246 : rules for exchanging quantifiers]

3) $¬∀x((Lx∧¬a=x)→Ex)$ --- [a] assumed the negation of the conclusion

4) $∃x ¬((Lx∧¬a=x)→Ex)$ --- from 3) by (RS)

5) $¬((Lb∧¬a=b)→Eb)$ --- from 4) by (DE) : Drop existential, with $b$ new

6) $(Lb∧¬a=b)$ and $¬Eb$ --- from 5) by (NIF) [page 196]

7) $¬((Lb ∧ ¬a=b) \land ¬Eb)$ --- assumed [b]

8) $(Lb ∧ ¬a=b)$ and  $¬¬Eb$ --- from 7) by (NOT-BOTH)

Now we have a contradiction in 6) and 8); thus, by RAA, we can derive :

9) $((Lb ∧ ¬a=b) \land ¬Eb)$ --- closing the innere sub-proof from assumption [b]

10) $¬(Lb ∧ ¬Eb ∧ ¬b=a)$--- from 2) by DU :Drop universal [page 248], re-using $b$

Now we have a new contradiction in 9) and 10); thus, using RAA again, we can derive :

> 11) $∀x((Lx ∧ ¬a=x) → Ex)$--- closing the outer sub-proof from assumption [a].

---

Similar for the direction : $\forall x (\ldots) \to \lnot \exists x (\ldots)$.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a proof presented in a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/). Since the "E" symbol is used to code the existential quantifier in the proof checker, I replaced "E" with "F". Also to make a well-formed formula from the second translation, I added parentheses.

There are three parts to showing that the two translations are equivalent:

1. Show $\forall x((Lx \land \lnot a=x) \to Fx) \to \lnot \exists x((Lx \land \lnot Fx) \land \lnot x=a) $.
2. Show $\lnot \exists x((Lx \land \lnot Fx) \land \lnot x=a) \to \forall x((Lx \land \lnot a=x) \to Fx)$.
3. Use biconditional introduction to derive the result from the first two parts.

Here is the first part:

[image]

One source of confusion may be how to commute the terms in the equality. Because the equality statement is negated I used an indirect proof to use equality introduction and elimination rules with non-negated statements.

At this point I could derive the result in part 1 above, but I will do that on the last line when I derive the biconditional.

The second and third parts come next:

[image]

Rather than attempting an indirect proof using the negation of the universal statement, I replaced $x$ with $b$ in the universal statement, used the equivalence $P \to Q \equiv \lnot P \lor Q$ to further transform the statement and then simplified it with De Morgan's laws. That resulted in line 21 in the proof checker. When I reached the contradiction on line 34 I still had additional work to do to derive the desired statement. That was done on line 44.

The third part took only one line. I used biconditional introduction on line 45 to complete the proof.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/